# Как проверить отправленное пользователем сообщение в телеграмме python telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Хочу сделать чтобы человек вводил рандомную капчу и программа проверяла её подлинность, но не могу преобразовать str в int.

```
import telebot

import random

from telebot import types


...

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def working(message):

        if message.text == "Начать":
            
            capcha = int(random.randint(10000,99999))
            
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, capcha)
            if message.text == capcha:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ответ верный")
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ответ неверный")

        elif message.text == "Список лидеров":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "В разработке...")
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чтобы пользоваться ботом нажмите "Начать"')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен в грамотности своего предложения, но что, если пойти от обратного и преобразовывать капчу в формат str, и затем сравнивать уже str-значения? Для этого после строки с генерацией капчи можно просто добавить что-то вроде
"capcha = str(capcha)". Если это решение не подойдет, расскажите, пожалуйста, почему - буду учиться :)

Comment: Я этот способ уже пробовал, не работает :(

Comment: А что идёт не так? Какая ошибка, что происходит?

Comment: Выдает вот эту строку  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ответ неверный")

Comment: Попробуйте добавить дополнительное преобразование текста сообщения в строку. Если я правильно понял синтаксис, то message.text - это метод класса. В таком случае, его содержимое можно присвоить переменной и уже переменную перевести в str-формат. Т.е. иметь следующие строки: message = message.text, message = str(message), capcha = str(capcha). Других идей у меня нет

Answer (score 0):

Вроде работает без доп функции это не решить наверно у тебя в message.text не капча

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def working(message):
    if message.text == "Начать": 
        global capcha;      
        capcha = int(random.randint(10000,99999))
        d = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, capcha)  
        bot.register_next_step_handler(d ,cap)

def cap(message):
    global d;
    d = message.text
    f = str(capcha)
    if d == f:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ответ верный")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ответ неверный")
```

Comment: переформулируйте, пожалуйста, вот это предложение (нажав [edit]): `Вроде работает без доп функции это не решить наверно у тебя в message.text не капча`. так, чтобы его смысл стал понятен не только вам.